# Binding in Code

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ScatterViewItem`, which contains a `UserControl`. I'm trying to bind the `MinWidth` of the `ScatterViewItem` to the `UserControl`.

```
ScatterViewItem svi = new ScatterViewItem();
MyUserControl myUserControl = new MyUserControl();

//Make UC follow SVI's size. This code works.
myUserControl.SetBinding(UserControl.WidthProperty, svi.Width.ToString());
myUserControl.SetBinding(UserControl.HeightProperty, svi.Height.ToString());

//Make SVI follow UC's Min size. This doesn't work.
svi.SetBinding(ScatterViewItem.MinWidthProperty, myUserControl.MinWidth.ToString());
svi.SetBinding(ScatterViewItem.MinHeightProperty, myUserControl.MinHeight.ToString());

svi.Content = myUserControl;
myScatterView.Items.Add(svi);
```

Why is it that binding UC to SVI works and not the other way? How do I bind the MinWidth of the SVI to the UC then?

Comment: Why use the `ToString()` the binding will be useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SetBinding method has 2 overloads (source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598270(v=vs.110).aspx):

> SetBinding(DependencyProperty, String)
>   SetBinding(DependencyProperty, BindingBase)

What you are trying to achieve by using the ToString() is not working, since the ToString() converts the value of the (Min)Width and (Min)Height properties to a string (for example 500.0 => "500.0"). The SetBinding overload that accepts a string as second parameter expects that string to be a property name or a path to the property.

<strike>What you probably want, is "MinWidth", "Width", "MinHeight" or "Height":</strike>

```
myUserControl.SetBinding(UserControl.WidthProperty, "Width");
myUserControl.SetBinding(UserControl.HeightProperty, "Height");

svi.SetBinding(ScatterViewItem.MinWidthProperty, "MinWidth");
svi.SetBinding(ScatterViewItem.MinHeightProperty, "MinHeight");
```

Edit: this is the correct version, using the other overload, since the previous piece of code doesn't know where to find the specified properties.

```
Binding widthBinding = new Binding("Width");
widthBinding.Source = myUserControl;
svi.SetBinding(ScatterViewItem.MinWidthProperty, widthBinding);

Binding heightBinding = new Binding("Height");
heightBinding.Source = myUserControl;
svi.SetBinding(ScatterViewItem.MinHeightProperty, heightBinding);
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly, other than a typo: `ScatterViewItem.MinWidthProperty` should be `ScatterViewItem.WidthProperty` and `ScatterViewItem.MinHeightProperty` should be `ScatterViewItem.HeightProperty`.

Comment: @DarrenNg Ah, just took that from your question.

Answer (score 1):

To bind your ScatterViewItem's MinWidth to your usercontrol's MinWidth, you need to create a binding with the source set to the usercontrol and path set to "MinWidth". This binding is then assigned to the ScatterViewItem with SetBinding.

```
// Create Binding
Binding b = new Binding("MinWidth");
b.Source = myUserControl;
// Assign Binding to ScatterViewItem
svi.SetBinding(ScatterViewItem.MinWidthProperty, b);
```